# Website not appearing in Google search results

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, google-search

I just recently took over a website that is hosted on GoDaddy to make enhancements to it. However, I am new to SEO and believe that I may have accidentally removed it from Google searches.

As stated, when googling for the website, I cannot find it anywhere. Whenever, I run a live test inspection on Google's search console, this is what I get...
[image]

[image]

I had some cache issues when I first made the site live with all of the upgrades, and may have unknowingly removed it from the search. However, I am still able to type in the actual address in the search bar and it will take me to the updated site.

These are the meta tags I am using along with one for keywords, description, and google-site-verification:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=yes">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

If there is anything I may be missing or something that you could help me out with, it would be greatly appreciated as I am new to using SEO.

Notes that may be helpful:

- I do not have a robots.txt file
- I am not using any meta tags with noindex

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! When you do a URL Inspection, click the Request Indexing link. You can make your work simple by inspecting the home page and requesting indexing. Look for the option to index linked pages or site. You will see if there is an error to work on or if you were successful. Google is very slow. Be very patient. Also, create a robots.txt file even if it is blank. This may sound like a silly thing to do, however, it is important. Let us know if you have an error. Otherwise, there is no key information for us to know what your problem is specifically. Cheers!!

Comment: Hello @closetnoc, I am the poster of this question, just signed in now with my stack overflow account. A couple things: I did request indexing for my page and that screenshot is the second screenshot i have posted. It returns the Not found (404) response. I'm not sure how "slow" google is, but the site has been live for a month or so, so not sure if that would be the issue or not. Also, as you said, I have just added a blank robots.txt file as well

Comment: Okay. If you are getting a 404 error, that is a problem. This is a server response which means Google is getting to your site but is getting an error that essentially tells Google the page does not exist. You may have a configuration problem or something else. Can you post the web server configuration just to make sure? It may help us to ask other questions. As far as Google Search Console, it can take months to update. Google does this to help combat spamdexing the search engine.

Comment: Ahhhh!! I just checked my web.config file and noticed it was pointing to a file that I deleted because I didnt think it was necessary. How dumb of me. Still trying to learn more about this stuff. Thank you for helping me realize this!! Just requested indexing in the google search console and it worked with no errors